# Disable cache for specific template

Tags: magento-enterprise, blocks, cache

I am using the Optimiseweb Cookie Notice module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/cookie-law-compliance-eu-uk-implied-consent-16757.html

I would need to disable the cache for the .phtml template. Here is the XML that takes care of loading the template file (as far as I understood):

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>

        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss" ifconfig="optimisewebcookienotice/general/enabled">
                <stylesheet>css/cookienotice.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="cookienotice/notice" name="optimiseweb_cookienotice" as="OptimisewebCookienotice" template="optimiseweb/cookienotice/cookienotice.phtml" />
        </reference>

    </default>
</layout>
```

**Edit:** After the below comments, here is what I have now:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <default>

        <reference name="optimiseweb_cookienotice">
            <action method="setCacheLifetime">
                <s>null</s>
            </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addCss" ifconfig="optimisewebcookienotice/general/enabled">
                <stylesheet>css/cookienotice.css</stylesheet>
            </action>
        </reference>

        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="cookienotice/notice" name="optimiseweb_cookienotice" as="OptimisewebCookienotice" template="optimiseweb/cookienotice/cookienotice.phtml" />
        </reference>

    </default>

</layout>
```

Is there a way that I can force the template to be **not** cached?

I have tried to change the cache lifetime in the block contruct function like below but that did not work:

```
protected function _construct() {

    $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime' => null
    ));
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this!

Comment: Not sure if it makes any difference but try 0 instead of `null`

Comment: I have tried many things there. `0`, `null`, `1`, `-1` but nothing ever changed anything (I manually clear the cache after each change to be sure that my changes are reloaded).

Comment: Since you are running Enterprise edition, is it possible that it is not cached by the block cache, but by the full page cache?

Comment: I have to empty the `Layouts` cache type for my changes to be loaded. Refreshing the `Page Cache` has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

you can use with xml like

You can use it

```
<reference name="your block">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>null</s></action>
</reference>
```

or

```
<reference name="your block">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime" />
</reference>
```

to set it to null.

or if you are using it by getChild then also pass as argument

You can disable cache in `getChildHtml().` This is what the signature looks like:

```
public function getChildHtml($name = '', $useCache = true, $sorted = false)
```

This should do the trick:

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('block', false);
```

Comment: Thanks. What should `"your block"` be replaced with in my case?

Comment: You should not set it to 0, because 0 will invalidate the cache each time, but you still have the caching overhead. Null really is the value you want to have in there.

Comment: There is no layout.xml in the module. It is not called with `getChildHtml` either. I have tried with `name=""` but it didn't change anything either.

Comment: What you call `layout.xml` is the XML I posted in my question? I am very new to Magento, sorry.

Comment: Tried it. Still no change. See my question edit.

Comment: http://www.magentothemess.com/archives/1876 could be help full

Comment: I already tried that too. Still no luck :(